# При выборе значения select изменить значения у всех select-ах на странице (клонирования выбранных значений)

Tags: javascript, html, select

Здравствуйте. На странице присутствует 3 select. При выборе значения в первом нужно чтобы то же значение отразилось во всех других. Аналогично если в первом ничего не выбрано, а выбрано во втором (третьем), то значения меняется также у всех. Например, если в первом выбрали text1, то во втором и третьем отображается text1, если во втором выбрали text2, то в первом и третьем отображается text2...
думаю вы поймете что я имею в виду

Клонирования двух select делаю так:

```
<select id="one" onchange="document.getElementById('two').value=value">
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option >text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
<select id="two" onchange="document.getElementById('one').value=value">
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option>text1</option>
    <option >text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
```

Пробовал сделать подобно через getElementByClassName для 3-x select-ов но ничего не получилось.

Думаю это не трудно сделать, но к сожалению я не знаю js. Заранее спасибо за Ваш ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">

<select id="one">
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option >text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
<select id="two" >
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option>text1</option>
    <option >text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
<select id="three" >
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option>text1</option>
    <option >text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>

</div>
```

js

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('select'),function(element,index,arr){

    element.addEventListener('change',function(){   
        var _value = this.value;
      Array.prototype.map.call(arr,function(e,i,a){
                a[i].value = _value;
            })

    },false)

})
```

рабочий пример https://jsfiddle.net/3t0z7qo3/ ( не завязан на хардкодное количество селектов)

Comment: Я опоздал, и да, так лучше намного :-)

Comment: Для стилизации select я использую EasyDropDown.js. через эту библиотеку не клонируются значения. Если удалить ее то все работает, но тогда нужно другой способ для стилизации select. Возможно, если Вас не затруднит подскажите другой способ для стилизации или возможно другое решение этой задачи?
Спасибо за ваш ответ  и решение.

Comment: @Endu, попробуйте сделать сниппет или фидл с подключенной библиотекой и разметкой. Там принцып тот же, разве что вместо option у Вас будут списки

Answer (score 1):

```js
function change(vart) {
  var one = document.getElementById('one');
  var two = document.getElementById('two');
  var three = document.getElementById('three');
  var curr = vart.value;
  one.value = curr;
  two.value = curr;
  three.value = curr;
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<select id="one" onchange="change(this);">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
<select id="two" onchange="change(this);">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
<select id="three" onchange="change(this);">
    <option value="0">Select option</option>
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clone(event)
{
      //заполнил массив элементами, грубовато, да
    var el = [document.getElementById('one'),
            document.getElementById('two'),
            document.getElementById('three')];

    el.forEach(function(item, i, el) {
        if (event.target != item)
            {
                item.value = event.target.value;
            }

    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="one" onChange="clone(event)">
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option>text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
<select id="two" onChange="clone(event)">
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option>text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
<select id="three" onChange="clone(event)">
    <option>Select option</option>
    <option>text1</option>
    <option>text2</option>
    <option>text3</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```